# Print contents of tree in level-order, using the eval function to read the input tree in python

Tags: python, recursion, tree, tuples

Part of the problem requires the tree to be printed in level-order, so if the input tree is:

```
("hello", (("a", ()), ("b", (("cde", ()), ("fg", ())))))
```

then the output should be,

```
hello

a b

cde fg
```

*** Note: the input trees can have any number of children ***

What seems to be unique here is that the tree should be inputted using,

```
tree = eval(input('Enter tree: '))
```

Most of the similar problems tend to use a Node class and/or a queue component which I have not found helpful for this problem and I can't find any cases where the eval function is used for input.

This is what I have so far,

```py
def level_order(node):
  label, children = node
  print(label)
  for child in children:
    level_order(child)

tree = eval(input('Enter tree: '))
level_order(tree)
```

My current program is able to print the contents, in what I think is pre-order traversal. How do I get it to print in level-order?

Comment: you need to walk the tree in a breadth-first manner ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do a breadth first walk of the tree

```
def level_order(*nodes):
    if not nodes: # base case
       return
    # all the labels and all the groups of chilren for this "level"
    labels,childrens = zip(*nodes)
    print("\t".join(labels))
    # flatten the list so instead of [[c1,c2],[c3,c4,c5,...]] we get [c1,c2,c3,...]
    flattened_children = [c for children in childrens for c in children]
    # call recursively
    level_order(*flattened_children)

level_order(("hello", (("a", ()), ("b", (("cde", ()), ("fg", ()))))) )
```

Comment: That works great! thanks! the only thing I don't understand is what the asteriks do i.e *nodes and *flattened_children?

Comment: pls1, though I tried to find some bultin library for tree parsing/traversal. Do you some kind of those in mind?